# access textarea value

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a  on a form of mine. I´m trying to reset the value (the value typed by the user) of this field on a certain event. However, I seem unable to access it both with .val() and .html().

Any advice on this?

Comment: provide your code please

Comment: yepp, that would make things more clear

Answer (score 5):

Do not use `.html()`, use `.val()`.

```
$("#your_textarea_id").val("Some literal <textarea> content.");
```

This way special characters (`<`, `>` etc) will show up correctly.

Comment: if I were you I would not suggest using `.text()` on <textarea>... http://jsbin.com/afuja3/2/

Comment: @Reigel: *Setting* a value with `text()` works perfectly fine. However, using `.val()` is probably still the better idea. My point was more about not to use `.html()`. (Code sample corrected, thanks for the hint.)

Answer (score 1):

Set an id on that field so you can easily target it with `$('#the_id')`.
If it's a textarea use .text(''), input use .val('')

Comment: Always use `text()` when setting text, not `html()`.  jQuery will attempt to parse valid HTML from the argument supplied to `html()`, which is not only slower but can also cause undesired effects when using `<` and `>` in the text.

Comment: yes... but also, do not use `.text()` on textarea... especially getting the value... use `.val()` instead... http://jsbin.com/afuja3/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#text_area').val("");
```